Absolute convergence of series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}e^{-(2n+1)a}e^{(2n+1)m(b-a)}$
How do I prove that the following series converges absolutely
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}e^{-(2n+1)a}e^{(2n+1)m(b-a)}$$ if we know that $b<0<a$.
The first thing I tried is proving that $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}|e^{-(2n+1)a}e^{(2n+1)m(b-x)}| < \infty .$$ I tried to rewrite the exponents to separate $a$ and $b$ and then somehow approximate series with their upper bounds which would hopefully converge. But I couldn't crach thw case because od the double summation.
I would appreciate your help.
Edit: Maybe I should also try somethimg with power series. Trying it now...

$e^{x}>0$ for all real $x$, so absolute values are not needed.

An alternative way is as follows $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{(2n+1)m(b-a)}={1\over 1- e^{(2n+1)(b-a)}}\le {1\over 1- e^{b-a}} $$ Thus the double  sum is less than $${1\over 1- e^{b-a}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-(2n+1)a}= {e^{-a}\over (1- e^{b-a})(1-e^{-2a})}$$

Hint: $-(2n+1) a+(2n+1)m(b-a)\le -(2n+1) a+m(b-a)$ (since $b-a <0$). Rest should be easy.
